# Can't connect to TightVNC server after latest Lunbuntu 20.04 update

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, vnc, tightvncserver

My TightVNC server seems to have been broken by the latest Lubuntu 20.04 update, which I applied this week. When I try to connect a client I get: "Failed to connect"

Any ideas for how to diagnose/resolve?

Log file is:

```
01/07/23 14:26:16 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.10
01/07/23 14:26:16 Copyright (C) 2000-2009 TightVNC Group
01/07/23 14:26:16 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
01/07/23 14:26:16 All Rights Reserved.
01/07/23 14:26:16 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
01/07/23 14:26:16 Desktop name 'X' (HP-MICROSERVER:2)
01/07/23 14:26:16 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
01/07/23 14:26:16 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5902
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/' not found - ignoring
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/' not found - ignoring
/home/myuser/.vnc/xstartup: 8: autocutsel-fork: not found
** Message: 14:26:17.901: main.vala:102: Session is Lubuntu
** Message: 14:26:17.901: main.vala:103: DE is (null)
** Message: 14:26:17.901: main.vala:113: No desktop environnement set, fallback to LXDE
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":2".
** Message: 14:26:17.923: main.vala:134: log directory: /home/myuser/.cache/lxsession/Lubuntu
** Message: 14:26:17.923: main.vala:135: log path: /home/myuser/.cache/lxsession/Lubuntu/run.log
Obt-Message: XKB extension is not present on the server or too old
Obt-Message: Xinerama extension is not present on the server
Obt-Message: XRandR extension is not present on the server
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":2".
Openbox-Message: Requested key "Print" does not exist on the display
Openbox-Message: Requested key "Print" does not exist on the display
Openbox-Message: Unable to find a valid menu file "/var/lib/openbox/debian-menu.xml"
AUDIT: Sat Jul  1 14:26:19 2023: 425147 Xtightvnc: client 10 rejected from local host
AUDIT: Sat Jul  1 14:26:19 2023: 425147 Xtightvnc: client 10 rejected from local host
```

Comment: I've repeated the install process for tightvncserver, and I can now connect, but my VNC client does not have a menu bar or status bar - only a few shortcuts on the desktop. If I right-click on the desktop I get a pop-up menu which gives me an option to open applications, terminal window, etc, but I don't get the full UI. ???

Comment: FYI:  You're aware that Lubuntu 20.04 LTS was a *flavor* of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and came with 3 years of supported life? (refer https://lubuntu.me/lubuntu-20-04-lts-end-of-life-and-current-support-statuses/ reaching the end of its three year supported life) with 5 years applying to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu base but not *flavors*. You're still on-topic here with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS questions though (*even if using LXQt*)

Comment: There have been no recent Lubuntu updates except for the supported releases of Lubuntu are 22.04 LTS, 22.10 & 23.04 only, so no Lubuntu team update has existed for a long time (no *backports* either for 20.04). It's likely a Ubuntu base update you're talking about, as you'll still be receiving those. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is still on-topic here (*you're now just trying to use LXQt desktop on 20.04*)